# Datedifference, conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I am comparing the Dates in my sheet. The Dates are in column H and I.

the date in column H is called as S.date and I is called as Start Date.

column H is completely filled, while column I have few empty rows.

I am having few cases,

Case1: if start date is > 4 weeks of s.date then i call it on time. 
eg: s.Date: 17.05.2017 and Start date is 20.06.2017, then ist called as on time.

case2: if the start date is < 8 weeks od s.date then i call it delay. 
case3 : if the sart date is between 4 and 8 weeks of s.date, then i call it as Remaining.

Case4: there are cases where i have the S.Date as 31.03.2017 and start date as 24.02.2017, I want them to be printed as green. How can i achieve this ?
Could anyone suggest how i could do it?

```
Sub status()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lrow As Long, i As Long
Dim zWeeks As Double, zcolour As Long
Dim Ztext As String
Set ws = Sheets("Result")
With ws
lrow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lrow
zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", .Range("I" & i).Value, .Range("H" & i).Value)
If .Range("E" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("F" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("I" & i).Value = "" Then
Ztext = "remaining"
zcolour = vbYellow
Cells(i, 11) = "Yellow"
ElseIf .Range("F" & i).Value = "" And .Range("I" & i).Value = "" Then
GoTo nextrow
ElseIf zWeeks < 4 Then
Ztext = "  on time"
zcolour = vbGreen
Cells(i, 11) = "Green"
ElseIf zWeeks > 8 Then
Ztext = " delayed"
zcolour = vbRed
Cells(i, 11) = "Red"
ElseIf zWeeks > 4 < 8 Then
Ztext = " remaining"
zcolour = vbYellow
Cells(i, 11) = "Yellow"
End If
With .Range("J" & i)
.Value = Ztext
.Interior.Color = zcolour
End With
nextrow:
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Image below Shows, the result needed. I am not able to acheive the green condition. Because in some cases, it Returns negative value, and it should be green. Please help me to code accordingly]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want cases... This is how your code should look like with them:

```
Sub Status()

    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim lrow        As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim zWeeks      As Double
    Dim zcolour     As Long
    Dim Ztext       As String

    Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    With ws
        lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To lrow
            zWeeks = DateDiff("ww", .Range("I" & i).Value, .Range("H" & i).Value)

            Select Case True

            Case .Range("E" & i).Value <> "" And _
                 .Range("F" & i).Value <> "" And _
                 .Range("I" & i).Value = ""

                Ztext = "remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 11) = "Yellow"
                Call ColorMe(i, ws, Ztext, zcolour)

            Case .Range("F" & i).Value = "" And .Range("I" & i).Value = ""
                'Do not write nothing here, to avoid the nasty goto

            Case zWeeks < 4
                Ztext = "  on time"
                zcolour = vbGreen
                Cells(i, 11) = "Green"
                Call ColorMe(i, ws, Ztext, zcolour)

            Case zWeeks > 8
                Ztext = " delayed"
                zcolour = vbRed
                Cells(i, 11) = "Red"
                Call ColorMe(i, ws, Ztext, zcolour)

            Case zWeeks < 8
                Ztext = " remaining"
                zcolour = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 11) = "Yellow"
                Call ColorMe(i, ws, Ztext, zcolour)
            End Select
        Next i

    End With

End Sub

Public Sub ColorMe(lng As Long, ws As Worksheet, Ztext As String, zcolour As Long)

    With ws.Range("J" & lng)
        .Value = Ztext
        .Interior.Color = zcolour
    End With

End Sub
```

What is changed:

- GoTo is avoided, as it should be used only in Error capture.
- I have added a module ColorMe(), in order to color only specific cases and not the 2. one.
- Pretty much that is all, it should work. If it doesn't I am pretty sure you will be able to adjust the conditions yourself.

Cheers! :)

Comment: still the case4 is not satisfied, i have it stil printing yellow. I want them in green. Because in few case as i have mentioned already, I have my s.date as 31.03.2017 and start date as 24.02.2017. I want them to be printed green. This gives the same result as the earlier posted code

Comment: should i post an Image, may be that would be clear for us to understand and work on it together_

Comment: in your code you dint consider the case4 i mentioned in the post.

Comment: i can simply Change the case3 in your code, but the Situation is, i want to check if the Dates are between 4 to 8 weeks and mention them as Remaining. if i have like case4 , then it goes to green (some spl cases)

Comment: Changing case 3 to case  >4 to < 8, something like this ? because case 4 is a spl condition, this is in reverse order, if the s.date is greater than the start date then it goes green, i belive we Need an case like this, and then goes the other cases . I am struck how i could do this. Can you help  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148779/discussion-between-mikz-and-vityata).

Comment: I have edited the post with an Picture, i am not able to achieve the condition for green